# How to speed up GUI CollectionView with lots of repetitive elements in .NET MAUI with XAML/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-interface, maui

Using .NET MAUI CollectionView with an ObservableCollection, is there any way to achieve the same visual results, based on the same data, without drastically slowing down the GUI/scrolling?

Can I sort of dynamically generate colored boxes instead of using `<Label>` elements in my XAML file, or use something else that makes it faster?

For the example below I only use 1 row with 12 columns but in reality every item has 7 rows with 24 columns, and there's 100's of items total, slowing down the GUI a lot. Every column needs a color based on an items value.

**XAML:**
Note: Using `<Label/>` elements is not necessary but apparently `<BoxView/>` does not support the `Background=""` property that I need for linear gradient brushes.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CalendarView">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Calendar">
            <Frame>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.jan,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.feb,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.mar,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.apr,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.may,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.jun,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="5"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.jul,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="6"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.aug,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="7"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.sep,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="8"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.oct,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="9"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.nov,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="10"/>
                    <Label Background="{Binding calendar.table.dec,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="11"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**C# code behind:**

```
private ObservableCollection<Calendar> calendars = new ObservableCollection<Calendar>();

private async void LoadCalendar()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var items = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Calendar>>("[api url censored]");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        calendars.Add(item);
    }

    CalendarView.ItemsSource = calendars;
}
```

**C# IValueConverter:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((int)value)
    {
        // These are linear gradient brushes! I used regular colors to simplify this example
        case 1: return Colors.Red;
        case 2: return Colors.Green;
        case 3: return Colors.Blue;
        default: return Colors.Transparent;
    }
}
```

**C# Data class**
This data is received through an API in JSON format, so this is a template.

```
public class Table
{
    public int jan { get; set; }
    public int feb { get; set; }
    public int mar { get; set; }
    public int apr { get; set; }
    public int may { get; set; }
    public int jun { get; set; }
    public int jul { get; set; }
    public int aug { get; set; }
    public int sep { get; set; }
    public int oct { get; set; }
    public int nov { get; set; }
    public int dec { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Jean-Marie Alfonsi wrote a useful [article about CollectionView performance](https://www.sharpnado.com/xamarin-forms-maui-collectionview-performance-the-10-golden-rule), which might be helpful here. It's about Xamarin.Forms, but should equally apply to .NET MAUI, since it's the successor. Generally, hundreds of items will slow down performance for sure. You should ensure that you use a fixed height for the items (c.f. linked blog article) and you may even want to lazy load additional items on demand instead of loading them all at once from your API.

Comment: Thanks, the tips have significantly improved performance!

Comment: Although still very laggy but at least it works now :)

Comment: As I've mentioned, you may want to add fewer items at the beginning and only add more when needed using a paging mechanism.

Comment: I solved it using a drawable canvas that paints the elements instead. Works like a charm!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea since nesting many controls consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: You can share your solution to help anyone who face this problem.